# Geocoding or adding region to imported Access table in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo

I have imported an Access database of 500+ sites into MapInfo. I've managed to geocode all but 80 of them against other tables that have the sites as regions with the same ID number, and replaced the geocoded objects with regions.

What can I do about the 80+ sites that have not been geocoded and need a region manually assigning to them? Selecting and adding a region just creates a new record. There is no object to do 'clear map objects' as there would be if the record was geocoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to manually draw a new region and have it assigned to an existing record with no spatial object, this is the way to do it:

1. Open a browser with your 500+ sites that have no spatial object

   Select * From 500_sites Where Not OBJ
2. Open a map with your 500+ sites (and other layers)
3. make the 500+ sites layer editable in the map

Now you are ready to start.

For each record with no spatial object do this:

- Select the record in the browser
- Switch to the map window without
  clicking inside the map as this resets your current selecting. You
  can click on the title of the map window or use Ctrl + Tab
- Select the Region tool
- Draw the region that should be assigned to the current record

And that's it. The trick is to select a record with no spatial object, by doing so and then drawing a new region (or any other spatial object) this object gets assigned to the selected record.

Comment: Thank you for answering my query so quickly!  I have created a table called 'ungeoded sites', in the way you suggest in points 1 and 2, and have been able then to assign the regions. Will I then need to append all the rows from this table to my original 500+ sites table, in order to have the whole database in the one mapping table, or join the two tables? I was wondering why this method wouldn't work just using the main 500+ table; I've tried it and it doesn't!

Comment: If you delete the records without spatial object from your main table you can append the new table to the original. However you can also just have created a query and shown the query in a browser (step 1)

Comment: Also I'd better ask when you say that you have created a table, you mean that you saved the records without spatial objects into a new table on disk, right?

Comment: To your last question, yes I did, and that was the one that I was amending, hence them not transferring to the main 500+ table. I'll do this via the query. Thank you very much for your help.